# Do I need a id column in audit table?

Tags: database, oracle

Many table designs I see around has a id column as a primary key. For example log_id in some Logging table, event_id in some event table and so and so. This column would have no dependency on any other column in any other table and uniquely identifies the record. From the look up perspective often times the columns used to look up information are other columns in the table that could be indexed as well (status/event_type/etc etc). So, what is the need to have such a id column representing the record in the table? If I were to remove such id column from a log table and may be instead use composite key what crime am I committing? Why is it so prevalent practice to have such a unique id column in a table where otherwise that column is not utilized in the application? Hoping to hear experts views. :o

UPDATE: Thank you all for quick replies! Primarily I would like to understand why it is so common practice to have a surrogate key instead of composite key in tables such as audit tables (there are other examples but trying to keep conversation focused). In such a table I could easily identify unique record by combination of event,userid and timestamp. Still most of the designs I researched online utilizes keys such as event_id. I am trying to understand why that if there is any real reason? In fact, wouldn't that mean consuming up unnecessary storage of db?

Comment: well, just google for surrogate vs natural key, the debate is not young  (and choose surrogate ;) )

Comment: Most of the time, you can retrieve an id column which is most of the time linked to a Primary Key constrain, making that id column an unique index. This same unique index that's allowing the SQL optimizer to determine a specific execution plan depending on specific elements (Number of elements to retrieve, volume, ...). If you're not planning to use the id anywhere else on your application, you should definitly define Indexes in your tables to increase performance.

Answer (score 3):

I make a distinction between tables that implement a real Relation in my data model, and tables that are just data-dumps for temporary, logging, audit trails, etc.

These are tables that have no Natural key - i.e. there is no combination of columns that can be guaranteed unique, but the duplicates have meaning; and there is not even a theoretical, logical Natural key that could be applied. In other words, it's not a real Relation per the relational model of data. We're just using a table for convenience.

In rare cases a table needs no key at all - a simple example is a log table that merely records events as they happen. It is only ever inserted into, and purging is done based on a timestamp (which, by the way, cannot be guaranteed unique). If there is no need for a key or a  surrogate key, there are no referential constraints, then I'll omit it.

But as soon as a table needs to be referred to *by the application* - e.g. if we need to refer to a particular record elsewhere - it is now part of the data model and we need to think about it as a Relation - i.e. what is its Natural key. Once that's established we can decide whether a surrogate key is needed or not.

Generally the only tables in my schemas that have no ID are ones that have no constraints at all - i.e. debug logs and audit trails (i.e. that log every insert/update/delete on a table). Everything else gets at least one unique constraint, if not more.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just an audit table I personally have no problem with a composite key. You need some sort of key because presumably you'll purge the log now and then, and with a key you can be selective.

The evil rep for composite keys comes mostly because some folks use real business values (SSN, Birth Date, etc.) to make up the keys, then proliferate them into related tables that have foreign key relationships to the parent.

This proliferation denormalizes the tables, plus *these values can change*. How? The most common is because they were entered wrong in the first place, but I have a client who's had to change SSN's for the following additional reasons:

- Customer got a new SSN due to identity theft.
- Customers who were "undocumented" and using fake SSN's, then become "documented" and got real SSN's.
- The big one: an executive fiat that all SSN's had to be stored encrypted.

Luckily, on my advice (and the advice of others), they weren't using SSN as part of their primary key so these changes were easy.

Another reason to avoid composite keys: they add complexity to a `JOIN`. But again, with an audit log you probably don't care.

Finally, I want to stress that I use ID-type values nearly 100% of the time, and have done so for well over a decade, so it's not a case of me being ambivalent to composite keys. I tend to avoid them, but again in your case I don't think it's a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

A composite key serves the same purpose as an ID.  If that meets your needs, then you're committing no crime.

However, if you find that the composite key you've chosen introduces collisions (you're returning more than one record when you expected one or none) then you'll need to re-evaluate your composite key.

Having an ID that is guaranteed to be unique and not re-used will circumvent this problem (at the expense of an extra field in your table).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other responses, I think another question to keep in mind is what uniqueness do you need to consider.  If you require a composite key to remain unique there are two choices:  1) Create the composite as a PK or 2) use a surrogate key (system generated number) and add another constrataint, alternate key on the composite (natural key).  That sometimes drive which I use.
Diane